# VBA Copying text from one worksheet to active worksheet

Tags: vba, excel, copy

Sorry for the basic question, but much googling only gave me complicated answers. On the click of a button I am making a copy of another worksheet, I need to copy some text from the first worksheet to this newly created worksheet on the same button click (who's name may differ I.e. sheet1 (1), sheet1 (2). I'm sure it's very simple referencing the active sheet, help appreciated.

```
 Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
 ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("AUTHORITIES VISIT").Copy _
 after:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("CREATE REPORT")
 End Sub
```

Comment: Just do `sheets("SHEETNAME")` that will reference the sheet name and then just select the text you want to copy. Just replace `sheetname` with the name of the sheet

Comment: The sheet name changes, I am copying from Sheets("CREATE REPORT") but I am pasting to the active sheet.

Comment: This falls over on the last line?

Range("b8").Select
 Selection.Copy
 ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("AUTHORITIES VISIT").Copy _
       after:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("CREATE REPORT")
       
 ActiveSheet.Range("C14").Select
 ActiveSheet.Paste


End Sub

Answer (score 0):

You can also have a look at the macro recorder and try it by your own.

This code should work for you:

```
Sub test()
Sheets("AUTHORITIES VISIT").Copy After:=Sheets("CREATE REPORT")
ActiveSheet.Cells(14, 3).Value = Sheets("CREATE REPORT").Cells(8, 2)
End Sub
```

As I understand from your comments above it copies the sheet "AUTHORITIES VISIT" after the sheet "CREATE REPORT" and copy from "CREATE REPORT" cell "B8" into the new sheet cell "C14"